# What's wrong with my simple SQL query?

Tags: sql

What is wrong with this SQL query?

```
SELECT
    department_id, MAX(AVG(SALARY)) 
FROM 
    EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY 
    department_id;
```

It shows not a single-group group function

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Unable to understand your requirement.

Comment: You cant have 2 aggregate functions,use a subquery

Comment: Can anyone suggest a solution to make this query work.

Comment: See my edited answer below

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

2 Aggregate functions in one Query can not be done, you should use a Subquery to achieve your result.

I've not possibility to test it right now so no guarantees on this query but you may get an idea.

```
select max (avg_salary)
from (select department_id, avg(SALARY) AS avg_salary
      from EMPLOYEES
      group by department_id);
```

The inner query selects deparment_id and average salary.
Avarage salary is selected using the alias avg_salary using the AS statement.

The outer query selects the maximum of avg_salary-

That's maybe not a complete solution to your problem and as I said, not tested so no guarantees, but you should have an idea now how to start. ;-)

Comment: One note: I think you should alias subquery.

Comment: thanks p9teufel. I got the output by slightly mofdifying your query

Answer (score 0):

You cant have more than one aggregate functions in one query. try this one

```
select dept, max(average) over (partition by dept) 
from  (SELECT department_id dept, 
             (AVG(SALary) OVER (PARTITION BY department_id)) average 
               FROM employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative 1, double `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT department_id, AVG(SALARY) 
FROM  EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING AVG(SALARY) = (select max(avg_sal)
                      from (select avg(salary) as avg_sal
                            from EMPLOYEES
                            group by department_id))
```

Will return both `department_id`'s if there's a tie!

Alternative 2, use a cte (common table expression):

```
with
(
  SELECT department_id, AVG(SALARY) as avg_sal
  FROM  EMPLOYEES
  GROUP BY department_id
) as cte
select department_id, avg_sal
from cte
where avg_sal = (select max(avg_sal) from cte)
```

This too will return both `department_id`'s if there's a tie!